# ADF How can I add prefix of output file?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using `CopyD Data` activity to read data from Kusto and export this data as `.csv` files in a container from a Storage Account.

Is there a way to export this files with the prefix name `export_` in each exported file without setting the `Max rows per file`?

Answer (score 0):

This is doable as below:

**Copy Data Activity Configuration**:

In the "Sink" section of your Copy Data activity, under the "Blob/File" section for the "Blob name" or "File name" option, you can define the name pattern. To add a prefix to every exported file, you can use the expression: `export_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss')}.csv`. This expression will prefix every file with `export_` followed by a timestamp, ensuring uniqueness.

To set a limit to the number of rows per file, leave the "Max rows per file" setting empty or unset.

Comment: I don't have those kind of options available for me. Does those options also appear when using ADLSv2 as `.parquet` file extensions?